# Laravel two modules in one project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I started to develop a backoffice in laravel (www.example.com/admin) and take use of MVC structure that is offered.
Now it is needed to develop online store in the same domain (www.example.com). What is the best approach to separate the two modules?
For instance one route file/controller folder for backoffice and other for the front site?
Best

Comment: You can try looking into [Caffeinated Modules](https://github.com/caffeinated/modules).

Comment: I have used Caffeinated Modules once but I guess it downloads about 200MB of dependencies :x

Answer (score 0):

Just like api and web routes are split in two separate files in Laravel 5.3, you could split admin and non-admin routes further in two separate files, passing different Controller prefixes (namespaces) to each one and adding an authentication middleware for admin routes. Look into your RouteServerProvider.php.

That's more than enough for a small-to-medium website IMHO.